# Great Orcs - how to tally terrain superiority?

Tags: the-battle-of-five-armies

In the 2014 game published by Ares Games, The Great Orc's ability says

> Any terrain type is considered to be favored when Great Orcs are attacking.

Who counts as having favorable terrain when the Great Orcs' ability is used? Does that ability apply to each individual Great Orc or does it automatically give the army as a whole terrain superiority?

Answer (score 1):

The rule wording could be better.

It means that each individual Great Orc counts the terrain as favored when they are in the attack. Other individual units have to check their terrain ability. Great Orcs in defense have no favored terrain.